# change url path using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a website for two different languages each being in two different folders `en` and `bn`. I want to switch between the folders on `href` element click using jquery.

```
<a class="eng_link " style="" href="#"> English</a> 
<a class=" link_active bangla_link " style="" href="#">বাংলা &nbsp;/ &nbsp;</a>
```

Say, I am currently on **www.example.com/en/content?id=1**. While clicking the link for english it will redirect to the url **www.example.com/bn/content?id=1** and vice versa. Only the `bn` part of the url will change to `en` keeping other parts the same. How can I do this?

Comment: First of all you have to save the language preference by any mean such as cookie. Second, you have to set a default language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I have done it.
In the index page of bn:

```
<a class="eng_link " style="" href="#" id='a' onClick="en_onClick()"> English</a> 
<a class=" link_active bangla_link " style="" href="index" >বাংলা &nbsp;/ &nbsp; </a>
```

JS

```
    function en_onClick() {
     $(location).attr('href');
     var bn_pathname = window.location.href;
     var en_pathname = bn_pathname.replace("bn/", "en/"); 
     window.location.replace(en_pathname);
 }
```

In the index page of en:

```
 <a class=" bangla_link link_in" style="" href="#" onClick="bn_onClick()"> বাংলা</a> 
 <a class=" link_active  eng_link" style="" href="#"> English &nbsp;/ &nbsp; </a>
```

JS

```
    function bn_onClick() {
     $(location).attr('href');
     var bn_pathname = window.location.href;
     var en_pathname = bn_pathname.replace("en/", "bn/"); 
     window.location.replace(en_pathname);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(".changeLink").click(function() {
  $(".eng_link").attr("href", $(".eng_link").attr("href").replace("en", "bn"))
});
```

[Here is the **JFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uLzj0cav/)

Comment: Is there any way to get the current URL and then replace "en" with "bn"?

Comment: Yes, using `window.location.href` will give u the current path, u can then replace and redirect

Comment: this will change all "en" in the text to "bn", like "en" in content ...

Answer (score 0):

use this function to change from any language to any language

in your html:

```
<a class="eng_link " style="" href="#" onclick="changelang('bn','en')"> English</a> 
<a class=" link_active bangla_link " style="" href="#" onclick="changelang('en','bn')">বাংলা &nbsp;/ &nbsp;</a>
```

and js:

```
function changelang(langfrom, langto) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var langfrom= "/"+langfrom+"/";
  var re = new RegExp(langfrom);
  url = url.replace(re,"/"+langto+"/"); 
  window.location = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative with jQuery and Javascript.

HTML

```
<a data-language="en" class="language eng_link " style="" href="#"> English</a>
<a data-language="bn" class="language link_active bangla_link " style="" href="#">বাংলা &nbsp;/ &nbsp;</a>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".language").click(function(e) {
        var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr("data-language");

        var currentContent = location.pathname.substring(
            location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1) + 1,
            location.pathname.length
        );

        console.log(selectedLanguage, " >> ", currentContent);

        // change URL to /en/content.html or /bn/content.html
        window.location.href = "/" + selectedLanguage + "/" + currentContent;
    });
});
```